# Angular 8 - How to load lazy modules into tabs

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying have tabs that would lazy load feature modules. Here is my code:

Main router:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
    {
      path: 'home', canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      loadChildren: './views/home/home.module#HomeModule'
    },
    {
      path: 'settings',
      loadChildren: './views/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule'
    },
  ]}
];
```

settings.module:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings.component';
import { SettingsRoutingModule } from './settings-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SettingsRoutingModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  declarations: [ SettingsComponent ]
})

export class SettingsModule { }
```

settings-routing.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { SettingsComponent } from './settings.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SettingsComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Settings'
    },
    children: [
      { path: 'syspref', loadChildren: './systempreferences/systempreferences.module#SystempreferencesModule' },
      { path: 'userpref', loadChildren: './userpreferences/userpreferences.module#UserpreferencesModule' },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
   ],
   exports: [
      RouterModule
   ],
   declarations: []
})
export class SettingsRoutingModule {}
```

settings.component.html

```
<section id="tabs">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="width: 100vw;">
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-syspref-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-syspref"
              aria-selected="false" routerLink="syspref">Default Preferences</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-userpref-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-userpref"
              aria-selected="false" routerLink="userpref">User Preferences</a>
                    </div>
        </nav>
                <div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-syspref" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-syspref-tab">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-userpref" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-userpref-tab">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

systempreferences.module

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SystempreferencesComponent } from './systempreferences.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  declarations: [SystempreferencesComponent]
})
export class SystempreferencesModule { }
```

My expectation was when I select a tab I will get a module such as SystempreferencesModule loaded and the SystempreferencesComponent component would show up, but that's not happening. Am I getting it all wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is happening when you click it?  Any devtools console errors?  Also I think your routerLinks are wrong. Should be routerLink="/settings/syspref" for the first one I think.

Comment: Also your SystempreferencesModule would need Routing setup as well.  'settings/syspref' should get you to that module but there's no routing setup on the module so it doesn't know what component to load.

Comment: I dont get any errors. I changed to /settings/syspref. No difference.

Comment: Will look into your latest comment.

Comment: I would check if the routing is working without the tabs and that tabs working without lazy load, and then the combination should be easy

Comment: If I change my router to this: { path: 'syspref', loadChildren: './systempreferences/systempreferences.module' } then I get an error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'default' in './systempreferences/systempreferences.module'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the old way of setting up lazy loaded routes.  This was changed in Angular 7 or 8 (I think...).  New way should be like this

```
{
    path: 'syspref',
    loadChildren: () => import('./systempreferences/systempreferences.module').then(m => 
    m.SystempreferencesModule)
},
```

Also in your SystemPreferences module you need a route like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SystempreferencesComponent,
  }
];
```

You can just add the routes variable at the top of your System Preferences module and add the below to your imports array (just slightly easier than setting up a routing module... functionally the same):

```
RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```